# php edit array value inside forloop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays, and I want to loop them while assigning a new key-value for each. But the original array fails to response. Here is my try:

```
<?php
$cards = array(
    array(
        "test" => 1  
    ),array(
        "test" => 2      
    )
);

foreach($cards as $card){
    $card["success"] = 1;
}

print_r($cards);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => 2
        )

)
```

How can I modify the method hence the 'success' value can be inserted into each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing array elements by reference (notice the `&` sign):

```
foreach($cards as &$card){
    $card["success"] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this. Here we are inserting value on the iteration of `$key`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778092)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$cards = array(
    array(
        "test" => 1  
    ),array(
        "test" => 2      
    )
);

foreach($cards as $key=> $card){
    $cards[$key]["success"] = 1;//Inserting value on the a key of $cards
}

print_r($cards);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => 1
            [success] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => 2
            [success] => 1
        )

)
```